# How to view neo4j database on the hosted linode server

Tags: neo4j, linode

I am running standalone neo4j database server at localhost:7474 on a linode instance.

Is there any way to view this in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSH access to the Linode instance then you can run `ssh -L 7474:localhost:7474 youruser@123.123.123.123` which will tunnel the remote port 7474 to localhost 7474. In your browser you can now use `http://localhost:7474` to see the remote server without opening anything to the world.

Answer (score 1):

You want what's called a "reverse proxy".  Outside of your box, you can't talk about localhost:7474 as a hostname.   So you want an external facing web server that "proxies" requests and sends them to localhost:7474.

One such option is [Apache mod_proxy used as a reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#examples).   Examples on how to use it are behind the link.   In general it's going to boil down to a configuration directive that looks something like:

`ProxyPassReverse /neo4j http://localhost:7474`

You also really want to read the documentation on [securing the neo4j server](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html).

**WARNING** - neo4j's web interface will let you do just about anything without authentication, including delete all of your data, change it, put new data in, and so on.   **It is a very bad idea to expose that functionality to the entire internet.**   So if you use a reverse proxy as suggested above, make sure you add some authentication layer (again you can do this with apache and mod_proxy) to permit just any random person from connecting to your instance and optionally deciding to trash it.